# What do I need to improve performance of the Android emulator?

Tags: hardware, android-emulator

I currently use Ubuntu 10.10, and I find the emulator extremely slow. However, I have an Intel Core 2 Duo CPU (T5200 processor) with 4G of RAM. What do I need to improve performance? Better hardware? A minimal Linux distribution?

Comment: Developer questions are off-topic, so I removed that aspect from the question since the emulator can be run by users too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Past versions of the emulator were extremely slow on all platforms.  However, there are now native x86 versions of the emulator; performance should be considerably improved.  You should be able to get them through the [Android SDK](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html) (or through Intel's website, see [this Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9821363/507761)).

However, I would recommend (for end users) [Memu](http://www.memuplay.com/) instead; it's very fast and reliable.  [Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/) is the best alternative if you aren't on Windows.

Comment: Thank you. I was thinking that I would need even more power for just an emulator. A dual-core with 4G is usually a good system, even by today's standards.

Comment: @jfmessier: I recall reading at one point that the emulator is actually confined to just one core, and that people tend to get better performance with a very high frequency single-core processor. That's probably where you're hurting the most - T5200 is fairly low on the Core 2 Duo frequency scale.

Comment: That makes much sense to me. And I realize that my cores are not the fastest ones. That would also mean that I should try to have a clean, small and fast installation of Linux that will leave more resources to Android emulator.

Comment: I have a quad-core machine, but it is a i7 intel chip, which does some extra clocking (turbo) when it sees that only one core is used. It does this in 133 MHz (some versions in 100 MHz) steps. I see some speed up for Honeycomb in the startup, but later the emulator is still not usable.

Comment: There are now native x86 images that run faster

Comment: @ce4 Indeed, I didn't see this old post to update it till now ;)

Answer (score 0):

As an update to [Matthews answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/12832/16575): I'm running Android-x86 in a [VirtualBox](http://virtualbox.org/) VM, performance and load are pretty much acceptable. Android-x86 images are available for [download on the project site](http://virtualboxes.org/images/android-x86/), and install in VM works like with any Linux distro (basically).

for detailed instructions, there are several tutorials around; simply google for [android-x86 virtualbox](https://www.google.com/search?q=android-x86+virtualbox), good matches appear already on the first page, e.g.

- [VirtualBoxHowTo](http://www.android-x86.org/documents/virtualboxhowto)
- [Install Android 4.4 Kitkat on PC or Virtualbox - YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o3YcSJJlxio)
- [The Complete Guide to Run Android 4.3 in VirtualBox](http://www.maketecheasier.com/run-android-4-3-in-virtualbox/)